# I am getting error when trying to plot two seperate lines in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I wish to write two different lines on heatmap. My code is

```
lines = [0,10,300,500,2560, 34500]
     with sns.axes_style("white"):
            f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(50, 50))
            ax = sns.heatmap(X)
            ax.axvline(4000, *ax.get_ylim(), ymin = lines[0], ymax = lines[4], lw = 8.0,  color = 'red')
            ax.axvline(4000, *ax.get_ylim(), ymin = lines[5], lw = 8.0,  color = 'green')
```

and I get an error like

```
TypeError: axvline() got multiple values for argument 'ymin'.
```

What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay there is a work around to the question. Commenter above mentioned that y axis should always take a number between 0 and 1.

So we can do a work around with percentage.

```
lines = [0,10,300,500,2560, 34500]
p_1 = lines[4]/lines[-1]
p_2 = 1
     with sns.axes_style("white"):
            f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(50, 50))
            ax = sns.heatmap(X)
            ax.axvline(4000, *ax.get_ylim(), ymin = 1-p1, ymax = p2, lw = 8.0,  color = 'red')
            ax.axvline(4000, *ax.get_ylim(), ymin = 0,ymax = 1-p1, lw = 8.0,  color = 'green')
```

Answer (score 2):

[According to the documentation,](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline), `axvline`'s signature is

```
axvline(x=0, ymin=0, ymax=1, **kwargs)
```

so when you do

```
ax.axvline(4000, *ax.get_ylim(), ymin = lines[0], ymax = lines[4],
```

(and `get_ylim()` returns a 2-tuple), you're passing `ymin` and `ymax` twice.

You'll need to either

- not use `*ax.get_ylim()`, or
- not use `ymin` and `ymax` separately.

Comment: I understand. But if my range of y-axis is [0,1] I can't plot a red line between 0 and 500. I wish my yaxis to be divded in the range I get from ax.get_ylim(), which is [0, 34500].

Comment: According to the documentation, `ymin` and `ymax` always range from 0 to 1, not your data range.